# Going from sheet to another sheet, not using select

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to get the code to "copy paste" the values in Sheet "X" Set as VBA. However it gives me a 1004 error.

```
Sub Probabilities()

Dim VBA As Worksheet
Set VBA = Sheets("X")
Dim Overview As Worksheet
Set Overview = Sheets("Overview")

Overview.Range(Cells(27, 3), Cells(34, 3)).Value = Overview.Range(Cells(40, 3), Cells(47, 3)).Value
VBA.Range(Cells(83, 3), Cells(88, 3)).Value = VBA.Range(Cells(83, 3), Cells(88, 3)).Value
```

The error is in this line:

```
VBA.Range(Cells(83, 3), Cells(88, 3)).Value = VBA.Range(Cells(83, 3), Cells(88, 3)).Value
```

Comment: If I had a pound for every time I've seen this..: `Overview.Range(Overview.Cells(27, 3), Overview.Cells(34, 3))` and the same for the others.

Comment: Hi @Rory, Code doesn't do as I wish for it to.. 

Exactly same error as before...

Comment: Then I guess you didn't change all of them as suggested. EG this: `VBA.Range(Cells(83, 3), Cells(88, 3))` needs to be `VBA.Range(VBA.Cells(83, 3), VBA.Cells(88, 3))` but you **really** shouldn't use VBA as a variable name!!

Comment: Hmm.. I changed it to this: 

'Overview.Range(Overview.Cells(27, 3), Overview.Cells(34, 3)) = Overview.Range(Overview.Cells(40, 3), Overview.Cells(47, 3))

   Calc.Range(Calc.Cells(83, 3), Calc.Cells(88, 3)) = Calc.Range(Calc.Cells(83, 3), Calc.Cells(88, 3)) ' 

Now the first line of the code doesn't even do what I want it to.
FYI i changed VBA to Calc

Answer (score 1):

```
With Overview
    .Range(.Cells(27, 3), .Cells(34, 3)).Value = _
    .Range(.Cells(40, 3), .Cells(47, 3)).Value
End With
With VBA
    .Range(.Cells(83, 3), .Cells(88, 3)).Value = _
    .Range(.Cells(83, 3), .Cells(88, 3)).Value
End With
```

Comment: Thanks that works! 

Can you help me create a loop, so that I can repeat this action 8 times; changing 1 column to the left each time (Holding the first line constant); I.e changing 
'Range(.Cells(40, 3), .Cells(47, 3)).Value' to Range(.Cells(40, 4), .Cells(47, 4)).Value and Range(.Cells(83, 3), .Cells(88, 3)).Value to Range(.Cells(83, 4), .Cells(88, 4)).Value

Thanks,

Comment: Or `.Cells(27, 3).Resize(7).Value = .Cells(40, 3).Resize(7).Value`

Comment: Bit of [scope creep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_creep) getting in there....

Comment: It fails when I put it in here: 
'With Calc
    .Range(.Cells(83, 3.Resize(7)), .Cells(88, 3).Resize(7)).Value = _
    .Range(.Cells(83, 3.Resize(7)), .Cells(88, 3).Resize(7)).Value '

Comment: @ValdemarE.Stage I addressed my comment to InExSu - not you. I just offered more concise notion. :) And yes - it can be in a loop. Just use variables instead of static numbers.

Comment: @ValdemarE.Stage With pleasure, but can't you use Google? :) There are tons of information on this theme. :)